# How to order an RSS Feed from a News Site by the Publication Date

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, rss

I am using .net 4 and reading a RSS feed from a News website - http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml?edition=uk

I have got the feed coming into the page using a repeater but I have just noticed that the feeds are not sorting Publication Date DESC all the time. There seems to be a strange grouping.

How am I able to explicitly specify that it is sorted by Publication Date DESC?

This is what I have so far...

```
private void PopulateRssFeed()
{
    //BBC UK 
    string RssFeedUrl = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/uk/rss.xml?edition=uk";

    List<Feeds> feeds = new List<Feeds>();
    try
    {
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
        xDoc = XDocument.Load(RssFeedUrl);

        //Take 3 Limits the number of items to display
        //i.e -
        //var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item").Take(3)
        var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                     select new
                     {
                         title = x.Element("title").Value,
                         link = x.Element("link").Value,
                         pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
                         description = x.Element("description").Value
                     });


        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var i in items)
            {

                Feeds f = new Feeds
                {
                    Title = i.title,
                    Link = i.link,
                    PublishDate = i.pubDate,
                    Description = i.description
                };

                feeds.Add(f);

            }

        }

        Repeater1.DataSource = feeds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ [`orderby ... descending`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383982.aspx) :

```
var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
             orderby (DateTime)x.Element("pubDate") descending
             select new
             {
                 title = x.Element("title").Value,
                 link = x.Element("link").Value,
                 pubDate = x.Element("pubDate").Value,
                 description = x.Element("description").Value
             });
```

As an aside, `items` can never be `null` so `if (items != null)` check is not needed.

Comment: Thank you - Thank you for the items null tip too.